# How to compute relative error of multi-dimensional time-series?

Tags: time-series, simulation, error, rms, dimensions

I have written a python script that uses a variety of different integrators to simulate the gravitational N-body problem. I would like to compare the positions obtained from my simulation to the positions as observed/calculated by an ephemeris. Suppose that each of the N bodies have a position array of shape `(t, d)` where `t` is the number of time-steps and `d=3` is the number of dimensions.

As a crude estimate, I calculated the square of the residuals of each vector component of position at each time-step, and summed over all bodies and vector components and time-steps. While this does help me select the "best" integrator, this does not quantify how right or wrong my simulation is. I would like to calculate the RMSE value of the positions, but most examples online assume scalar values. I am not sure how to proceed. One possible idea is to convert the vector position coordinates into a scalar distance away from the center-of-mass (since the ephemeris is given in this frame), and then to sum over all bodies. But, I am not sure if this is correct.

Is there a standard method to compute relative error for a multi-dimensional time-series?